# How to transfer the Ethereum blockchain to another user session?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, windows

My client was not syncing at all. I have installed a new wallet in another user session with new wallet addresses.

Wallet 2 for user 2 on the same Windows 10 machine has downloaded the entire blockchain but Wallet 1 for user 1 is three months late.

Is there a way to copy the blockchain from one user session to another one to go faster in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy your `chaindata` folder from one user session to another.

What you might be seeing is that your old chain is processing blocks one at a time, which is slow whereas your new wallet fast synced. It is a security consideration to disable fast sync after the initial sync phase.